# Value error x and y must be same size, but they are?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot to numpy arrays both of length 10 against one another:

```
mass_frac_plot = plt.figure()
mass_frac = mass_frac_plot.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
mass_frac.scatter(mass_frac, homogen_frac)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plot.py", line 58, in <module>
    mass_frac.scatter(mass_frac, homogen_frac)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3836, in scatter
    raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
```

Help! They really are both arrays and of length 10...

```
print(type(mass_frac), len(mass_frac))
print(mass_frac)
print(type(homogen_frac), len(homogen_frac))
print(homogen_frac)
```

Gives this:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 10
[ 3.67  3.6   4.45  3.74  4.93  4.35  3.89  5.62  4.73  3.83]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 10
[  98.02982123   96.82921968   88.8207858    83.37174016   75.55236146
87.71156752   91.95410515   66.34245085   77.63112123  119.74640558]
```

Comment: Is one a 10x1 array and the other a 1x10 array? Only thing I can think of... maybe try transpose one?

Comment: What do you get when you print the array shapes, e.g. `print(mass_frac.shape)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Help! They really are both arrays and of length 10...

No, they're not:

```
mass_frac_plot = plt.figure()
mass_frac = mass_frac_plot.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
^^^^^^^^^
mass_frac.scatter(mass_frac, homogen_frac)
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

After you execute your second line, `mass_frac` is clearly no longer an array at all.  Instead, it'll be of type

```
>>> type(mass_frac)
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

Change the variable name so you're not clobbering your array.

Comment: Oh sweet jesus. Thanks!